# BeautifulSoup remove special characters of contents of tag

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to compare a string with the contents of a html page. But the special characters in the HTML page makes this comparison harder. So I want to remove all the special characters and white spaces from the HTML page before comparison. But all the tags must remain the same.
that is

```
<div class="abc bcd">
         <div  class="inner1"> Hai ! this is first inner div;</div>
         <div class="inner2"> "this is second div... " </div>
</div>
```

this should be converted to

```
<div class="abc bcd">
          <div class="inner1">Haithisisfirstinnerdiv</div>
          <div class="inner2">thisisseconddiv</div>
</div>
```

How this can be done?

Comment: Figure out how to replace text with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

Find all the leaf tags and change their strings.

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrtsuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def replace(soup):
    for child in soup.children:
        if child.string:
            child.string = ''.join([ch for ch in child.string if ch in alphabet])
        else:
            replace(child)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

orig_string = """
<div class="abc bcd">
         <div  class="inner1"> Hai ! this is first inner div;</div>
         <div class="inner2"> "this is second div... " </div>
</div> """

soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_string)
print soup.prettify() # original HTML
replace(soup)
print
print soup.prettify() # new HTML
```

Output:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="abc bcd">
   <div class="inner1">
    Hai ! this is first inner div;
   </div>
   <div class="inner2">
    "this is second div... "
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<html>
 <body>
  <div class="abc bcd">
   <div class="inner1">
    Haithisisfirstinnerdiv
   </div>
   <div class="inner2">
    thisisseconddiv
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a little thing, `import string; string.letters` produces the alphabet both lowercase and uppercase :)

Comment: For Unicode awareness, don't enumerate all letters. Instead, import `unicodedata` and rather than `ch in alphabet`, use `unicodedata.category(ch)[0] == 'L'`.

Comment: Also, your `child =` in the `child = replace(child)` is useless.

Comment: @icktoofay Got rid of the `child=`. You're right about the Unicode, of course, but I don't think oP is looking for Unicode support.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `BeautifulSoup` already fixes up some broken HTML when calling `BeautifulSoup()` So:

```
<div  class="inner1">
```

Goes to

```
<div class="inner1">
```

Here's how to get rid of the whitespace and special characters:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<div class="abc bcd">
     <div  class="inner1"> Hai ! this is first inner div;</div>
     <div class="inner2"> "this is second div... " </div>
</div>""" 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for divtag in soup.findAll('div'):
...     if 'inner' in divtag['class'][0]:
...         divtag.string = ''.join(i for i in divtag.string if i.isalnum())
>>> print soup
<html><body><div class="abc bcd">
<div class="inner1">Haithisisfirstinnerdiv</div>
<div class="inner2">thisisseconddiv</div>
</div></body></html>
```